# validation to text area is not working how can i debug it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

hi  I have a form with different feilds all validations are working except this text area im unable to bebug can you help me out.

```js
// jquery script overview  
var overview = $("#overview").val();
if (overview == '') {
    $("#overview").css({"border-style": "solid", "border-color": "red" });
    $("#showMessage").html('Please Write In Overview');
    $("#overview").focus();

    return false;
} else {
    $("#overview").css({"border-style": "solid","border-color": "#E9E9E9"});
}
```

```html
//Form
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Over View</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <textarea name="overview" id="overview" style="width: 360px; height: 150px;">Enter text here...</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the console of your navigator to debug it?

Comment: How can i do that in browser->inspect..?

Comment: press F12 in browser.

Comment: Unable to find in that way

Comment: http://jsbin.com/batiberu/3/edit?html,output    try this

Comment: is your js code inside `$(document).ready()` ?

Comment: In chrome just press F12. There is a tab named Console. There you can test every instruction. Or you can go to Sources, search your code and use an interrupt point to execute it manually

Comment: It is submitting without validation  Is my syntax is correct..?

Comment: yes it is jqury   $("#participant").click(function()
 {

Comment: @ranjan  your link is working finally but i want to implement without taking outsource help is it possible..?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed there is a possible way using javascript with popup shall I provide it. http://jsfiddle.net/35DFR/2/ check here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(overview =='')
```

will never be true unless you explicitly remove the text you have added. Use placeholder that will work

```
<textarea name="overview" id="overview"  placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
```

and yes don't forget to `trim` the string when comparing for empty values.

Comment: Still not working i have replace my textarea with yours and jquery as well

Comment: @AbdulWaheed are you calling it using event or the code is in document,ready? can you post the complete code?

Comment: i am calling it by button id @danyal

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line

```
var overview = $("#overview").html();
if(overview =='' || overview == null)
```

you can not get the value of textarea with val() method becoz textarea has not a value attribute.

Comment: i want to focus red if empty

Comment: place all your js code in one function and call this function on the keyup and down event of textarea or you can call on when user click submit button.

Comment: can you write code please i am little new to jquery validations

Answer (score 1):

You will need to place the validation code inside `.submit` . Simply return `false` on `onclick` event will not prevent form submission.

```
$( "#your_form_id" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  if ( ..validation code returns true..) {
      alert( "Submitting form..." );
  } else {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submission
  }
});
```

Comment: this is ajax submission brother @jason

Comment: This piece of code does not submit the form. It adds an event listener to your form, and it is triggered when the form submits. You can do validation inside it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
//form
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/dist/validator.min.js"></script>

<textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Text Here..." style="width: 360px; height: 150px;" id="overview" class="form-control" required></textarea>
```